# Python: Trying to use recursion to determine descending order, but variable is seemingly changing itself in the process

Tags: python, list, recursion, conditional-statements, global-variables

I'm trying to make a function that returns whether or not a List is in descending order by using recursion, but the variable `descending` seems to be changing from `True` back to `False` on its own. Also, I recognize this is likely not the best way to find descending order or even doing so with recursion (and I will gladly take suggestions); however, I would still like to understand this issue regardless if possible. The code is:

```
global descending
descending = False

def desOrder(numList):
    if not numList:
        descending = True
        return
    if max(numList) == numList[0]:
        del numList[0]
        desOrder(numList)
    return

numCopy = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
desOrder(numCopy)

if descending:
    return 0
```

I have tried adding print statements throughout to see where the source of the issue lies, but I have not been successful. `desOrder(numCopy)` will trigger the `if not numList` statement and change `descending` to `True`, but then the `if descending` statement is still recognizing `descending` to be `False` and not returning 0 as expected. Also, the `numCopy` variable is just an example for simplicity and in the actual program the `desOrder` function uses a copy of the desired List so the original is not altered. Thanks for any help

Comment: You need `global descending`. But it would be better if the function returned its result rather than setting a global variable.

Comment: This is a very inefficient algorithm. You don't need to check if the first element is the maximum, just check if it's more than the second element. And the recursion can stop when the list has 1 element.